# error after trying to escape single and double quoted string in a variable using python

Tags: python

I've tried escaping `\` the single and double quotes within a single quoted string, but I'm still getting an error.

Here's my syntax and what I'm trying to do:

```
mydim='hummer'
mycat=int(subprocess.check_output('zcat export-cars.csv.gz | awk \'BEGIN {FS=\";\"};{print $6}\' | grep -i %s | wc -l'  %mydim, shell=True))

if mycat > 0:
   print ('Yes')
else:
   print ('No')
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

Is there another way to set my variable with this mix of quotes?

Comment: Why don't you use python instead of this complicated shell command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same task in pure python:

```
import gzip

lines = gzip.open('export-cars.csv.gz')
mycat = sum(line.split(';')[5] == mydim for line in lines)
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I did try this, however I'm getting a `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: `. I tried putting in the full path and got the same error.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the file exists in that path? Double-check it.

Comment: `with gzip.open('/home/test/export-cars.csv.gz') as lines:
...     mycat = sum(line.split(';')[6] == mydim for line in lines)`. I set `mydim='hummer'`. I get this message: `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: GzipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__'` and definitely the file is there.

Comment: then try it wihtout `with`.

Comment: Ok, i got through, removed `with` and it opened the file - `<gzip open file '/test/export-cars.csv.gz', mode 'rb' at 0x7fcc8a7a2c00 0x7fcc8a702290>`, however, how do I run the next line? `mycat = sum(line.split(';')[6] == mydim for line in lines)`?

Comment: don't understand the querstion, run the line with python.

Comment: @Daniel - Thx for your help on this. I'm getting close. No errors in the syntax. Now, i'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a value of `0` when I do have records there. From what I understand `[6]` should be the same as column position right? Like my `$6` in my shell command? I also changed tried changing mydim to `hummer` which is the string I am grepping for.

Comment: `5` is correct, because python counts from 0, awk from 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 wc -l'  %mydim, shell=True))
```

you never close this quote
It's most likely causing your problem.

Comment: I changed it to this and added the space between `% mydim` and still no luck: `mycat=int(subprocess.check_output('zcat export-car.csv.gz |  awk \'BEGIN {FS=\";\"};{print $6}\' | grep -i %s | wc -l'  % mydim, shell=True))`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'`

Answer (score 0):

1. You missed backslashes on `{print $6}'` and `wc =l'`, then you didn't close the quote after `%mydim` (which is where the shell command appears to end).
2. The traceback is saying that it couldn't find `check_output` in `subprocess`, which seems like a separate issue.